# Warning to update the architecture while validating the ipa

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, warnings, cpu-architecture

Has anyone else received that warning while uploading the application to App Store?

Everything was going well before today, but when I started to upload the application I began getting the below warning, telling me to update the architecture to support 64-bit.

When I performed the function asked of me, I began getting a lot of errors. If I upload it with a warning will it affect my other code?

We build the app in unity pro 4.5.5 and exported the project to Xcode with iOS 7.0 as build target. Now when we are changing it to standard architecture which consist of arm64 we get lot of errors stating that the unity libraries are not supporting arm64 architecture.

Please let me know if anybody is facing a similar warning while uploading the ipa and any preferable solutions or suggestions are welcomed. Thanks in advance for help.

[image: relevant code]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the errors?

Comment: There are lot of errors around 196 and I have exported the project from unity and the errors are due to unity's lib file..so it gonna be bit tough.

Comment: Try if Unity 4.6 (beta) fixes this.

Comment: Hi @LearnCocos2D thanks for suggestion but I guess this also won't work. If you see http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/788853/ios-arm64-missing.html# link he also tried and it still supports armv7. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity 4.6 latest version is fixing the armv64. So from now if you create a project in unity for iOS please update it to 4.6 and then create. Cheers.